# Is there a Maven plugin to create Jenkins job

Tags: maven, jenkins, maven-plugin

I have about a hundred maven projects for which I would like to create Jenkins jobs.  Instead of creating the jobs by hand, with the likely attendant mistakes, is there a way to create from a maven plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There is the [job-dsl plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) which allows you to build jobs in a groovy DSL

This works by providing a build step in a separate job

You can loop through your jobs as explained [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/31216b7487b28e3858e616b388f6d2314ffbce87/docs/Real-World-Examples.md)

```
def giturl = 'https://github.com/quidryan/aws-sdk-test.git'
for(i in 0..10) {
    job("DSL-Tutorial-1-Test-${i}") {
        scm {
            git(giturl)
        }
        steps {
            maven("test -Dtest.suite=${i}")
        }
    }
}
```